# how to delete all property from object in typescript except some properties

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript, arraylist, iterator

I want to delete all property from the object in typescript except some properties those I want in the object.
I want three properties to remain (start_time, latitude, and altitude)
my list object:

```
listObject= [
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T08:12:11.706Z",
    "latitude":20.4841203,
    "longitude":77.8726691,
    "duration":0,
    "completed_by":0,
    "started_by":0
  },
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T08:00:17.441Z",
    "latitude":20.4840866,
    "longitude":77.8726445,
     "altitude":272,
    "started_by":0
     "duration":10,
  },
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T09:06:28.039Z",
    "latitude":20.4840631,
    "longitude":77.872614,
    "datastream":"ABC",
  },
  {
    "altitude":0,
    "latitude":0,
    "longitude":0,
    "start_time":"2018-03-28T11:26:16.332Z",
    "Average":60,
    "Name":"Navi",
    "Price":42699
  }
]
```

and I want only following list object:

```
listObject= [
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T08:12:11.706Z",
    "latitude":20.4841203,
    "longitude":77.8726691,
  },
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T08:00:17.441Z",
    "latitude":20.4840866,
    "longitude":77.8726445,
  },
  {
    "start_time":"2018-03-24T09:06:28.039Z",
    "latitude":20.4840631,
    "longitude":77.872614,
  },
  {
    "altitude":0,
    "latitude":0,
    "longitude":0,
    "start_time":"2018-03-28T11:26:16.332Z",
  }
]
```

please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your **JSON** is wrong, it was missing some **`,`** on object properties. Here is the corrected **`JSON`**.

Also you can use **[`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to iterate over the objects and create new objects with your properties.

**DEMO**

```js
var listObject=[
  {
    "start_time": "2018-03-24T08:12:11.706Z",
    "latitude": 20.4841203,
    "longitude": 77.8726691,
    "duration": 0,
    "completed_by": 0,
    "started_by": 0
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2018-03-24T08:00:17.441Z",
    "latitude": 20.4840866,
    "longitude": 77.8726445,
    "altitude": 272,
    "started_by": 0,
    "duration": 10
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2018-03-24T09:06:28.039Z",
    "latitude": 20.4840631,
    "longitude": 77.872614,
    "datastream": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "altitude": 0,
    "latitude": 0,
    "longitude": 0,
    "start_time": "2018-03-28T11:26:16.332Z",
    "Average": 60,
    "Name": "Navi",
    "Price": 42699
  }
];

var newList = listObject.map(obj => ({start_time: obj.start_time, latitude: obj.latitude, longitude: obj.longitude}));

console.log(newList);
```